# .htaccess redirect https://one.com/mydir/feed/4e7a5135?param=1 to https://two.com/direct_feed/4e7a5135?param=1

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

i wanted .htaccess redirect.

```
https://one.com/mydir/feed/4e7a5135?param=1
```

to

```
https://two.com/mydir/direct_feed/4e7a5135?param=1
```

Already tried :

```
RewriteRule https://one.com/mydir/feed/(.*) https://two.com/mydir/direct_feed/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Where's the PHP for this?

Comment: Sorry its .htacess redirect only

Comment: i wanted to redirect it notice this id : 4e7a5135 , but also wanted if any get parameter added to it.

Comment: This whole redirect would be better handled in the application logic. If you must, then a `RewriteCond` on `%{QUERY_STRING}` would be necessary. `[QSA]` already reapplies the existing parameter. If you need someting more specific, please edit and elaborate more concretely. Input URLs and target paths, plus RewriteLog (enable it!) are always helpful.